# opengl shader make color "disappear"

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, augmented-reality

I'm new to opengl and shaders. I'm trying to do some augmented reality on the iphone and messing about with shaders to alter a feed from the camera.

What I'm trying to achieve is the appearance that an object in a picture has disappeared by setting the color to match the surrounding colour. I have a yellow rectangle and in it is a small red circle. I want to give the impressed the red circle has disappeared by setting the colour to be yellow.

It won't always be solid colours but I'm just trying to get the basics down first.

Currently I have a simple shader which will make a red colour lighter but this isn't ideal because it doesn't get close to the surrounding colour and I want this to work for different coloured objects and different coloured surrounding.

I'm not even 100% shaders are what I need to be looking at or even opengl. I'm using it because of the performance it gives on the iPhone.

I'm basically asking if:

1. Anyone has done or seen anything similar
2. Am I barking up the wrong tree using opengl es and opengl sl?
3. Is this even possible?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of alpha blending?
Colors have 4 channels. Red, green, blue, and alpha (rgba). The alpha channel determines the transparency. You can set it to anything in between 0 (fully transparent/invisible) or 1 (fully solid).

To make your object invisible, simply set alpha to 0!
For example in your frag shader:

```
gl_FragColor.a = 0;
```

You can achieve this without using shaders by changing the alpha value from your program.
For example:

```
glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5); //Draws something red with half transparency (hence the 0.5)
glVertex3f(...);
glVertex3f(...);
glVertex3f(...);
```

Just make sure you have alpha blending enabled:

```
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: I don't have access to the object to set its transparency because the image is coming from the video feed of the iPhone so I don't think this approach would work, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Is it an API call to render the image from the camera feed, or is it a texture that you draw? Is it the image itself you need to make transparent or the objects you draw over top?

Comment: its the image itself, i'm not drawing any objects over the top. after a bit more googling i found this: http://www.kurzweilai.net/diminished-reality-software-removes-objects-from-video-in-real-time - this is what im trying to achieve. it is an api call to render the image

Comment: That changes everything. This is out of the bounds for normal renderering techniques used by OpenGL. This kind of stuff takes advanced image processing. Granted, OpenGL shaders can be used to speed up the process, but the process itself is a complicated one.